# Possible equivalence of quantum particle and the quantum scalar field theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

I have been doing some reading and calculations in Zwiebach's 2nd edition text of " A First Course in String Theory". After some calculations, I have a conceptual question. Let me ask the question first then motivate it after that.

**Question**

Is quantum scalar field theory equivalent to the quantum mechanics of a pair of harmonic oscillators? If this is true and with the knowledge that a complex scalar field can be described as two real fields (through a straightforward mathematical mapping), how does this scale the number of oscillators at the quantum level?

**Let me lay some foundation and motivate the question**

Take in basic form as a starting point the lagrangian density describing a scalar field:

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial_0 \phi \partial_0 \phi - \frac{1}{2} \partial_i \phi \partial_i \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2$

skipping a bit ahead:

$\vec{P} = - \int  d^d x (\partial_0 \phi) \nabla \phi$  . . . . (10.46)

After some calculations, one can find

$\vec{P} = \vec{p} (a^* _p a_p - a^*_{-p} a_{-p}  )$   . . . . (10.47)

These are two harmonic oscillators.

After some more calculations, it can be shown that at the quantum level, the Hamiltonian  becomes an operator

$H = E_p (a^\dagger _p a_p + a^\dagger _{-p}{a_{-p}}  )$    . . . .  (10.55)

This describes "a pair of simple harmonic oscillators, each with frequency $E_p$ "

The state space can then be constructed.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/737996/2451

Comment: You are missing various negative signs. For example, (10.47) as currently written vanishes.

Comment: That portion of your book is dealing with one only mode of the field, with a particular wavevector. The field has an *infinite* number of modes. Scalar waves can propagate in any direction with any wavenumber, just like vector waves do in electromagnetism.

Comment: Quantum field theory would not have mathematical difficulties (such as infinities requiring renormalization) if it reduced to two harmonic oscillators. The difficulties arise because it has an infinite number of arbitrarily high-energy oscillators.

Comment: @Ghoster I am editing to try to do the _p . Having some difficulties doing the Tex for that, and then I will address the other comments right after

Comment: It’s a minus sign: a_{-p}

Comment: got it I was literally using underscore. Let me fix that

Comment: The underscore introduces the expression to be subscripted. It needs to be in braces if “composite”. The subscripted expression is negative.

Comment: Ok, I think I have corrected the expressions now

Comment: Yes, they look OK now. They even have the same unevenness in the subscript placement that Zwiebach has, because that’s just how TeX does it unless you get fiddly.

Comment: @Ghoster On the modes of the field, I think I see what you are saying. I thought I was onto something for a second there.